# In Flutter, Why async function in gridview builder looping nonstop

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is functions of getting last data from realtime database

```
Future<double> getLastDoc(int idex, String name) async {
    String location = "";
    double val = 0;
    for (String i in sensors.keys) {
      if (sensors[i]['name'] == widget.list) {
        location = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('items/$location/$name');
    Query query = ref.limitToLast(1);
    final dataSnapshot = await query.once();
    if (dataSnapshot.snapshot.exists) {
      Map data = dataSnapshot.snapshot.value as Map;
      for (var i in data.values) {
        EvapData json = EvapData.fromJson(i);
        val = json.winder;
        print(val);
      }
    }
    return val;
  }
```

After that, I compare it with a double value to determine whether to show a warning or not.

```
void compareWinder(int index, String name, double set) async {
      await getLastDoc(index, name).then(
          (value) => value > set ? showWarning = true : showWarning = false);
      setState(() {});
    }
```

Here is the funtions return widget to use in grid view builder.

```
Widget listOfSensors(int index) {
      String name = widget.list[index][0];
      compareWinder(index, name, double.parse(widget.list[index][2]));
      return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: const Color(0xFF393053),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: ListTile(
                  leading: showWarning
                      ? const Icon(
                          Icons.warning,
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                        )
                      : null,
                  title: Text(
                    widget.list[index][0],
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white, fontSize: mobile ? 15 : 20),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    widget.list[index][1],
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white, fontSize: mobile ? 10 : 12),
                  ),
                  trailing: Icon(
                    Icons.launch_rounded,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: mobile ? 20 : 30,
                  )),
            ),
          ));
    }
```

And here is a body in Scaffold. (widget.list.length is 1)

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
          child: DynamicHeightGridView(
            builder: (context, index) => listOfSensors(index),
            itemCount: widget.list.length,
            crossAxisCount: mobile ? 1 : 2,
            mainAxisSpacing: 10,
            crossAxisSpacing: 20,
          )),
    );
```

After I try to run it seems like compareWinder function is looping instead of loop once(list length). Appreciate any feedback on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Its not going to loop only once because you placed the `compareWinder` function inside the builder, and asking it to call the function for each index. So it will get called multiple times during layout buildup and rendering process for every index.

What you can do is remove the `compareWinder` function from the builder (`listOfSensors` in this case) and use a FutureBuilder to get a list of bool results first, and then start the builder process based on the results. I'm not sure if this would work out for you, but here is an example

I would first simplify your `compareWinder` to return a bool value:

```
Future<bool> compareWinder(int index, String name, double set) async {
  double value = await getLastDoc(index, name);
  return value > set;
}
```

Then add it in a new list in FutureBuilder:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: FutureBuilder<List<bool>>(
    future: Future.wait(List.generate(widget.list.length, (index) {
  String name = widget.list[index][0];
  return compareWinder(index, name, double.parse(widget.list[index][2]));
})),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
      } else {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
          child: DynamicHeightGridView(
            builder: (context, index) =>
                listOfSensors(index, snapshot.data ?? false),
            itemCount: widget.list.length,
            crossAxisCount: mobile ? 1 : 2,
            mainAxisSpacing: 10,
            crossAxisSpacing: 20,
          ),
        );
      }
    },
  ),
);
```

Your listOfSensors widget doesn't need to build an async function anymore since the `FutureBuilder` handled it, you just need to simply pass it:

```
Widget listOfSensors(int index, bool showWarning) {}
```